# Sum 3rd level column values grouping by 1st level keys in a 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I want to convert the following 3-level array to a flat, associative array of columnar sums per first level key. Do I need to use a `foreach()` or can `array_sum()` do this?

```
[
    'Sum_1' => [
        ['e' => 1000001, 'u' => 'Test1', 'a' => 775.00],
        ['e' => 26, 'u' => 'Test2', 'a' => 555.00],
    ],
    'Sum_2' => [
        ['e' => 1000001, 'u' => 'Test1', 'a' => 110.00],
    ],
    'Sum_3' => [
        ['e' => 1000001, 'u' => 'Test1', 'a' => 444.00],
    ],
]
```

I want to get the sum of element `[a]` of each section (e.g. `Sum_1`, `Sum_2`, `Sum_3`).

Desired result:

```
[
    'Sum_1' => 1330.00,
    'Sum_2' => 110.00,
    'Sum_3' => 444.00,
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do like this:

```
$ret = array_map(function($val) {
  return array_sum(array_map(function($val) {
     return $val['a'];
  }, $val));
}, $array);
```

Prior to php 5.4:

```
function a_getter($val) {
    return $val['a'];
}
$ret = array_map(function($val) {
    return array_sum(array_map('a_getter', $val));
}, $array);
```

Comment: @xdazz I was able to do the sums without an array, on the template itself. Thank you anyway. I don't really understand your method. I know what array_map and array_sum do, but can't really understand how they are used in your code? can you explain a bit or direct me to a useful source? Thank you

Comment: @ThiliniIW Check how array_map work will be help. array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

Comment: "[Callables](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.callable.php)" can be used from php 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Using a `foreach` loop, you can try this:

```
$sums=array();
foreach($ArrayOfSums as $Offset=>$ArrayOfResults){
    foreach($ArrayOfResults as $ResultOffset=>$Result){
        $sums[$Offset]+=$Result["a"];
    }
}
```

[Result](https://3v4l.org/1ohcY):

```
Warning: Undefined array key "Sum_1"

Warning: Undefined array key "Sum_2"

Warning: Undefined array key "Sum_3"
array (
  'Sum_1' => 1330.0,
  'Sum_2' => 110.0,
  'Sum_3' => 444.0,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make mapped calls of `array_sum()` on the `a` column values of each data subset.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t5UOr))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($rows) => array_sum(
            array_column($rows, 'a')
        ),
        $array
    )
);
```

Or use nested loops and perform basic arithmetic on the nominated column values.  Remember to default the key's value to 0 if it has not yet been pushed into the result array -- this avoids PHP Warnings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a74QL))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as ['a' => $a]) {
        $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $a;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```